# Mongodb, Typegoose - generic repository pattern

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

@typegoose/typegoose": "^7.2.0"

Is there any way to have generic CRUD repository with typescirpt and typegoose?
In particular, how to get the method `getModelForClass()` work with generics?
Something similar to this code borrowed from the [question 246](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/246) .

If so, what am I missing?

```
import { prop, getModelForClass } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import { AnyParamConstructor, ReturnModelType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types';

export class GenericCRUDService<T, U extends AnyParamConstructor<T> = AnyParamConstructor<T>> {
  dataModel: ReturnModelType<U, T>;

  constructor(cls: U) {
    this.dataModel = getModelForClass<T, U>(cls);
  }

  public create(data: T) {
    this.dataModel.create(data);
  }
}

export class Cat {
  @prop()
  public age: number;
  @prop()
  public color: string;
}

export class Dog {
  @prop()
  public isBarking: boolean;
  @prop()
  public race: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ref: [typegoose/typegoose#303](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/303)*

if you want an "manager class" and not the actual model to be generic, this is easy, you just need to have the right types

i would recommend to write the class like:

```
// NodeJS: 14.4.0
// MongoDB: 4.2-bionic (Docker)
import { getModelForClass, prop, types, ReturnModelType, DocumentType } from "@typegoose/typegoose"; // @typegoose/typegoose@7.2.0
import * as mongoose from "mongoose"; // mongoose@5.9.18 @types/mongoose@5.7.27

export class GenericCRUDService<U extends types.AnyParamConstructor<any>> {
  public dataModel: ReturnModelType<U>;

  constructor(cls: U) {
    this.dataModel = getModelForClass(cls);
  }

  public create(data: mongoose.CreateQuery<DocumentType<InstanceType<U>>>) {
    this.dataModel.create(data);
  }
}

export class Cat {
  @prop()
  public age?: number;

  @prop()
  public color?: string;
}

export class Dog {
  @prop()
  public isBarking?: boolean;

  @prop()
  public race?: string;
}

(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/`, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: "verifyMASTER", useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

  const CatService = new GenericCRUDService(Cat);

  await CatService.create({}); // with type support (since ~@types/mongoose@5.7.21)

  await mongoose.disconnect();
})();
```

(your problem by taking the old example is that since [7.1.0](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/changelog#710) the "unnecessary" `T` generic got removed)

Comment: Hihi, long time here.h
I've been trying to use your example in my code but I got the following error 

```
  userManager: Manager<User>;
  public router = Router();
  private jwtService: JwtService;

  constructor() {
    this.jwtService = new JwtService();
    this.userManager = new Manager<User>(User);
    this.initializePaths();
  }
```

The error> 
```
Type 'User' does not satisfy the constraint 'AnyParamConstructor<any>'.   Type 'User' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.
```

Do you have something in mind?

Comment: @Andres this code formatting makes it hard to read, though if you have a error similar to ` Type 'User' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'` and `User` in this case being a class, try `typeof User` where the error occurs. also the error seems unrelated to the question / answer